# SO_REUSEADDR just make sense for server?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, udp, so-reuseport

I am working with two binaries which use UDP sockets. Process A waits for messages on a UDP socket (IP_1:PORT_1) by `select()`, and process B eventually sends through an UDP socket.

By some constraints out of scope, process B needs to send by a socket on (IP_1:PORT_1). Since this is the same IP:PORT pair for both processes, it is not possible to use `bind()`. I tried `SO_REUSEADDR`, but **I am wondering if reusing the IP:PORT with `SO_REUSEADDR` for sending and receiving makes sense, or was this option conceived just for listening sockets?**

process A

```
int nOptVal = 1;
setsockopt(UDPSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &nOptVal, sizeof(nOptVal));
bind(UDPSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&addrLocal, sizeof(addrLocal));

select(fdMax+1, UDPSocket, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

process B

```
int nOptVal = 1;
setsockopt(UDPSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &nOptVal, sizeof(nOptVal));
bind(UDPSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&addrLocal, sizeof(addrLocal));

sendto(UDPSocket, buff, len, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&addrDest, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
```

Comment: The SO_REUSEADDR option typically makes most sense for passive connection-oriented sockets (like a TCP server socket).

Comment: The problem with this setup is that one can use setsockopt, but messages will be send to either one of the sockets. So process A will not be able to reliable receive messages (as much as the non-reliability of UDP would allow anyway).

Comment: Just what I was afraid of, @SteffenUllrich, thank you. So although is possible this setup, doesn't make sense because I loss messages.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, so then I would say that the setup I propose is not correct due to process A will loss messages, and ONLY makes sense for passive connection-oriented